# Laravel - don't show the same record twice using inRandomOrder()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query to get a random question from my database:

```
$q = Question::inRandomOrder()->first();
```

Each question i'm generating is saved at `user_questions` with the following structure:

```
id | question_id | user_id
```

My goal is to generate the random question using the eloquent query above and exclude all questions the user already has.

For example, if there are the following records in my user_questions table:

```
1 | 133 | 234
2 | 134 | 234
3 | 543 | 234
```

the query that return a random question excluding **133,134 and 543**.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you'll have to find a way to match the retrieved random query against an array of already answered one. If in it, ignore, otherwise, display to user. If there's something like 'ifExist' you could do, then you check the column for some data, if there, pull out, otherwise, try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`whereDoesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) to exclude questions which user already has:

```
$randomQuestion = Question::whereDoesntHave('users', function($q) use($userId) {
         $q->where('id', $userId);
    })
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->first();
```

Comment: I've been using your previous answer, using `whereNotIn('id',$questions)` and it did the trick. my `$questions` is a list of all questions the user already has. I couldn't understand your updated answer and if it can perform better.

Comment: Yep, new answer is more readable I guess, but `whereNotIn()` will also work if you already have IDs of user's questions. Glad it helped. )